# dd cloned win2003 std ntfs partition, "no operating system found"

Tags: windows-server-2003, clone, dd

I cloned an existing ntfs partition on faulty hardware using dd and gzip. The copied partition was then written to a newly created ntfs partition on a new disk (on another server) and the bootable flag was set.
However, the "Operating system not found" (or is it No operating system found?) is what happens when I try to boot it.
The faulty server is part of the AD domain, but I do not have the local administrator password, so I couldn't use the repair console of windows 2003 to fixmbr. I did try to do a normal repair during win2003 installation menu, but with no success.
Both windows installation and Linux recognizes it as a ntfs partition of its true size, and files can be seen and read.
I've done this a couple of times before, but I didn't encounter this problem. Of course I encountered other problems, like BSDO due to lack of hw drivers etc - but that was pretty easily fixed.
Why am I failing to get the copied partition to even be recognized as a bootable disk on the new server?

Comment: The faulty hardware has memory problems and boots just fine, but BSODs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to backup from faulty machine also the MBR of the disk ?

for backup the MBR with dd run this on faulty machine :

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/home/aleroot/boot.mbr bs=512 count=1
```

and then for restore the MBR in the new machine :

```
dd if=boot.mbr of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1
```

You could run this dd commandline booting up the machine with a GNU/Linux Live CD image like Knoppix.

Comment: It suddently dawned on me that I in stress copied the first 512 bytes of sda1, not sda. It's probably that simple! Will test it today.